# how to add labels without them overlapping each other

Tags: java

I wanted to add 2 labels in my JDialog; one label will have animated gif ; other will have text. How to add these two so that they dont overlap? I don't want to hardcode their positions. I want the program to make the inherent adjustments.

Thanks in Advance

code:

```
     JLabel l2=new JLabel("");
     try {

          Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resources/wait_animated.gif"));
          ImageIcon imgnew=new ImageIcon("G:\\my java\\DesktopApplication1\\src\\desktopapplication1\\resources\\wait_animated.gif");
          l2.setIcon(imgnew);
          imgnew.setImageObserver(l2);
     }
     catch (IOException ex) {
     }
     l2.setLocation(300,300);
     JDialog d=new JDialog();
     JLabel l=new JLabel("Please Wait While Processing is Done...        ");

     JDesktopPane dp=new JDesktopPane();
     dp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,50));
     l.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,50));

     l2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,20));

     d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
     d.setTitle("Wait dialog");
     d.add(l);
     d.add(l2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do realize that one label can have both text and an image, right?  E.G.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.URL;

class AnimatedGifInLabelWithText {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final URL url = new URL("http://pscode.org/media/starzoom-thumb.gif");
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(url);
                JLabel label = new JLabel("Zoom!", ii, SwingConstants.CENTER);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. No, i was not aware that i could do that.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please also look closely into Bombe's suggestion.  It is *vital* to understand how layout managers work, when creating GUIs in Java.  It is rarely necessary to set the size, preferred size, or location and bounds of a component manually.  That is what layout managers are for.  Once the layout managers have done their work, a call to pack() on the top level container will have it sized to the minimum required to display the components it contains.  Like magic.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`LayoutManager`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html) (such as [`FlowLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html)) to arrange your labels. It’s hard to say without any more details.